# How do I tell if my goldfish is pregnant?

Tags: aquarium, fish, goldfish, pregnancy

I'm new to keeping fish. I picked up 3 comet goldfish a couple of months ago. They've been living in the same tank and one is getting bigger, way bigger than the other 2.

Is it pregnant? How can I tell?

Comment: you need to give a lot more information and if possible post a picture,goldfish do lay eggs so they do not get pregnant.how big are the goldfish?.

Comment: @trondhansen Not sure we need a picture from the OP.  How to tell if a GoldFish is pregnant or ready to lay eggs should be pretty generic, with an answer(s) that apply to anyone who has a goldfish.

Comment: how about sonography?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, it is a little diifcult without a picture to really determine that your goldish is pregnant or not... but if it seems like it's belly is getting big, then it might be.

If your goldfish is getting big overall in length and height, etc. that is natural since comet goldfish do end up getting pretty big!

I recommend taking a read [here](https://petsofun.com/pregnant-goldfish/) for best practices in the case that your goldfish is bearing baby fish!